# Is there a way to have ssh offer more keys to login automatically?

Tags: ssh, login

I've learned at myriad sources online that (roughly), in order to login to a remote server without a password: generate an ssh key, put the pub version in authorized_keys on the remote system; put the private version in your local ~/.ssh/ directory; chmod it to 0600 and poof, you're in. While that is mostly correct, I find that the key (pair) has to be named id_rsa (id_rsa.pub) or id_dsa (id_dsa.pub) for SSH to offer it to remote servers.

Let me back up a bit. I have a login, `SurnameG` on my local Mac. I have a SurnameG account on a remote system, otherserver.

I copied the contents of `~/.ssh/surnameg.pub` to that system's /home/surnameg/.ssh/authorized_keys. I've tested with the `-i` option from my Mac to ssh in and it works fine.

I have an `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (which I generated for use with *github.com*).

And of course, I have `~/.ssh/surnameg` and even some other keys there, which are not being "tried" when I try to login the following way to *otherserver.com* :

```
ssh 1.2.3.4
```

Here, I am trying to use `SurnameG` (the current local logged in user) to login to my `SurnameG` account on *otherserver*. I am wanting openssh to offer `~/.ssh/surnameg` in its attempt to connect, but it does not - let's take a closer look with the verbose option:

```
BOX:~ SurnameG$ ssh -v 1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [50.112.132.124] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ax:64:3e:4a:e3:2c:e4:30:dd:36:a4:a0:9x:fa:ba:6b
debug1: Host '1.2.3.4' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/known_hosts:88
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/SurnameG/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Curiously, openssh only offers ~/.ssh/id_rsa, but that's not all. It "tries" ~/.ssh/id_dsa also? I'm not sure on the difference between the two (offering versus trying) Anyway, if I am reading that correctly, openssh never tries any of my other private keys in `~/.ssh/*`.

Okay, I know I can explicitly describe each server in `~/.ssh/config` with something like

```
Host otherserver
   HostName 1.2.3.4
   User surnameg
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/surnameg
```

and then login with

```
ssh otherserver
```

and that's fine and dandy and works great. But really, my ~/.ssh/config is getting unwieldy. Sadly I didn't `cd ~/.ssh && git init` a long time ago. But I digress.

My question is this: Is there a simpler, faster, more automated way to get ssh to try more keys in the ~/.ssh directory dynamically when attempting logins, or is editing your ~/.ssh/config for every server you need to connect to the only way to configure ssh? Have I misunderstood anything above about how SSH is supposed to work?

Comment: You are supposed to use helper programs like ssh-add and ssh-copy-id. Check those manpages.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you answered your question (well, not answered the part about whether or not you understood ssh), you're supposed to use your ~/.ssh/config for this.  The things ssh tries by itself are the hardcoded names of id-files it will generate automatically when you a) chose a type and b) don't provide a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to offer the same keys to all hosts, load them into a SSH agent using `ssh-add`. Many Linux distributions start one automatically – try `ssh-add -l` to check if it's running, then load your keys:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/surnameg etc.
```

---

If the agent not started automatically, put the following in your `~/.profile`:

```
agent_running() {
    [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && { ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>&1 || [ $? -eq 1 ]; }
}

env=~/.ssh/agent.env
if ! agent_running && [ -s "$env" ]; then
    . "$env" >/dev/null
fi
if ! agent_running; then
    ssh-agent >"$env"
    . "$env" >/dev/null
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_*
fi    
unset env
```

Comment: Thanks @grawity - this is going to work out fine. When I ran `ssh-add -l` it says `The agent has no identities.` Does that mean it's running, but I am loading no additional keys (yet)? Also for future readers, you will need to rename private keys to id_* to match glob on line 11 in the script above.

Comment: @phpguru: Yes, it's running but empty. And yes, the rename is intentional, as `~/.ssh/*` would catch too many irrelevant files.

Answer (score 4):

There is another possible approach. You can use placeholders in the `IdentityFile` option in `ssh_config`. As per [`man ssh_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5):

- `%d`—local user's home directory
- `%u`—local user name
- `%l`—local host name
- `%h`—remote host name
- `%r`—remote user name

I use it like this (in the global `ssh_config` file):

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%r@%h
```

This means my private key files are named like `daniel@example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, but it doesn't really answer my question.